# Stuck with getaway car in GTA V and no hints in the top right corner

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I am pretty sure it's mission 36, I need to do truck and trash car and masks and clothes. I did all, but I can't get ANY getaway car. I know it has to be four seats. But I tried every car. No car gave me hint like: This car can be used as getaway car. I can't progress now.

**I tried to do:** suicide, restart the game, call Lester/Michael, but without any outcomes.

**Cars I've tried:** Cheval Fugitive, Emperor Habanero, Albany Primo, Ubermacht Oracle XS, Karin Intruder...

Comment: It's worth noting that the Cheval Fugitive is the default getaway vehicle when this mission is replayed. Moreso than any other vehicle, that one should be a valid one to use for the heist.

Comment: It can happen that the information doesn't get prompted to you, if you get another prompt at the same time or if you're in another activity such as another mission or hanging out with strangers and freaks. You can ultimatively check it by playing Franklin or Trevor, finding a 4-door car and calling Michael on the phone. The Dewbauchee Exemplar is a fast 4-door often found in north Vinewood or Rockford Hills. Don't forget to park it somewhere rather secluded like in the very north of Vinewood Hills or around Blaine Country. It still has to be near any kind of road, so don't park it in a bush.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem has been solved. I tried next day and I tried Cheval Fugitive and it works.